# chrome_options.add_extension adds the extension in switch off mode

Tags: chrome-options

I am using chrome_options.add_extension to add the extension into chrome browser and it works fine but the extension is loading in switch off mode. How can i handle that in script.

```
        chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_extension(ExtensionPath)
        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(Chromepath, options=chrome_options)
```